# Count number of times duplicates appear

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling with this one.

Column A has a students name.
Column B has the name of the exam they took.

If they fail the exam they will need to take it again.

I would like to know which exams are being failed the most, by counting the attempts at the exam. For other reasons I can't just count the total amount of different exams, as some students will not take every exam, and therefore some exams will have a total count very high.

I need to establish with random students names, how many are taking a second or third attempt.

I'm hoping to use count and not start populating more columns with each students name against a exam subject.

Comment: I think "the curse of knowledge" is at play here, in that you have been thinking about a problem that you understand the inner workings of for some time, and so explaining it makes complete sense to you. However, for those of us coming into it from square one, it really is not clear at all. I suggest that the most effective and efficient way to illustrate your end goal is to set up a sample spreadsheet containing realistic raw data and the manually-entered results you'd like to see, along with an on-sheet explanation of those results.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.